# How to remove a Zero if it is the first digit?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first attempt at making a javascript and I've only started learning about 2 weeks ago, so bare with potential newbishness. Im basically just trying to convert an international number to what needs to be actually dialed.

I need to figure out how to remove a leading zero from the phonenumber variable and no other zeros. Ive seen answers on this that involve parseInt and other solutions but I cant figure out how to implement them.

```
<script>
var countrycode = document.getElementById("country").value;
var phonenumber = document.getElementById("phnm").value;
function updatecountrycode() // Updates country code on user change //
 {countrycode = document.getElementById("country").value;}
function updatenumber() // Updates phone number on user input //
 {phonenumber = document.getElementById("phnm").value;}
function fullnumber() // Displays country code + phone number //
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 9011 + countrycode + phonenumber};
</script>
<form>
Choose the country you want to call
<select id="country" onchange="updatecountrycode();">
<option>Choose Country</option>
<option value="44" id="uk">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="353" id="ire">Ireland</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
Enter Phone Number
<input type="text" id="phnm" onchange="updatenumber()"><br>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="fullnumber()">complete number will display</button>
<p id="output">test</p>
```

Comment: If you edit your question, put a bold EDIT above it so that people who already answered your question will see your request for clarity or additional information.  You will normally be better off responding directly to the answers by commenting, though.  That way, the person who answered it will get an alert notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a fiddle for you.
https://jsbin.com/dotoha/edit?html,js,output

parseInt solution works fine, because e.g. praseInt('032132323') will produce `32132323` and for multiple leading zeros it will work as well

e.g. parseInt('0003434344434') will give `3434344434`

```
var countrycode = document.getElementById("country").value;
var phonenumber = document.getElementById("phnm").value;

function updatecountrycode() {
  // Updates country code on user change //
  countrycode = document.getElementById("country").value;
}

function fullnumber() {
  // Displays country code + phone number //
  var phonenumber = document.getElementById("phnm").value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 9011 + countrycode + parseInt(phonenumber);
}
```

Comment: I used this solution and it solidly worked. I had tried parseInt(phone number) before but didn't have the variable again in the fullnumber function. If you don't mind, what is the reason it had to be there again and the initial var declaration wasn't enough?

Comment: @AaronB - check out http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp to read about scope in JS.

Comment: great... you just need to get phone number at the time when you submit number because before that updating that phone number variable using `updatenumber` function is unnecessary. So just get value at button click, parse it to number and then concatinate

Comment: Actually, nevermind.  I looked at the fiddle and the second "var" is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution:

```
if (phonenumber.substr(0,1) == "0")
{
    phonenumber = phonenumber.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `.charAt(0)`?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
var PhoneNumber = "0545";
var PhoneNumber = parseInt(PhoneNumber, "10");
```

Problem solved.  The second parameter for parseInt (10) is to indicate a decimal based number (default is 8-based).  But, parsing your number as an integer will easily remove leading zeros - and you don't have to worry about substrings or if statements.

Comment: Btw. default is not 8-based, and doesn't need to be a string, but a number because this way looks weird since you're parsing the string which is the parameter of the parse function. But yeah, it will work.

Comment: When your leading number is a zero, the default is 8-based (now deprecated, so it appears your are correct):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I know I am late on this question but I think this question is still relevant for some users, so I would like to share a simple function which I have created to remove zero for a text box.

To use this function simply parse your value as an argument in this function i.e removeZero(yourValue)

```
function removeZero(v) {
    if ( v.charAt(0) == 0 ) {
        return v.slice(1);
    }
}
```